# Marking inserted objects as public with GoLang Google Cloud Storage API

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Golang [package storage v1](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/storage/v1) to upload files to Google Cloud Storage, 
using the following method:

```
func (r *ObjectsService) Insert(bucket string, object *Object) *ObjectsInsertCall
Insert: Stores a new object and metadata.
```

Everything works great except I'm not sure how to publicly expose uploaded files, using Google's developers console I can manually set a file public by clicking the Public link checkbox,
Any idea how do I achieve the same result using the above API? an example would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [PredefinedAcl](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/storage/v1#ObjectsInsertCall.PredefinedAcl) function on ObjectsInsertCall. Predefined ACLs are [described in the API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert), but one of them is "public-read", which marks the object as globally viewable.